API no funciona cuando ejecuto una sentencia SQL
estoy haciendo una practica para hacer una API Rest con ASP .Net Core, y todo funcionaba bien al principio, pero ahora que la he conectado a una base de datos me muestra este mensaje cada que intento probrarla con una inserción de datos, me pueden decir como solucionarlo. Ya intente deshabilitando la opción "solo mi código" desde el visual y desde el archivo .cjsproj

'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Private.CoreLib.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'F:\Cursos\CursoWebAPI\CursoWebAPI\bin\Debug\net6.0\CursoWebAPI.dll' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Runtime.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\projectsystem\net6.0\Microsoft.WebTools.ApiEndpointDiscovery.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Linq.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Collections.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\8.0.400\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\8.0.400-rtm.24374.10\tools\net8.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Browser Link\Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\professional\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\hotreload\Microsoft.Extensions.DotNetDeltaApplier.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.IO.Pipes.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Console.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Threading.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Security.AccessControl.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Security.Claims.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Runtime.Loader.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\netstandard.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.ComponentModel.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'F:\Cursos\CursoWebAPI\CursoWebAPI\bin\Debug\net6.0\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: F:\Cursos\CursoWebAPI\CursoWebAPI
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Net.Sockets.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Net.Security.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Net.NameResolution.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.33\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.33\System.Net.WebSockets.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
El programa '[19044] iisexpress.exe' terminó con código 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.


Hola, esto pasa por lo general por 3 motivos, problemas con dependencias, problema en configuracion de IIS o bien problemas en el codigo, con  la informacion que brindas es muy complejo indicarte cual de las 3 es el problema.

Y el error?? porque ahi estas mostrando la traza de compilacion, no el error...

Pues es que no me muestra ningún error, por eso no lo pongo solo me muestra ese mensaje
